# Commutation of 27 functions

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

### Introduction

Let's define a *ternary function* as a function from the three-element set `S = {0,1,2}` to itself: it associates to each element of `S` another element of `S`.
One example of a ternary function `f` is

```
f(0) = 0; f(1) = 2; f(2) = 0
```

There are exactly 27 different ternary functions, and we represent them with integers from 0 to 26: a function `f` is encoded as `f(0) + 3*f(1) + 9*f(2)`.
The example function above is encoded as the number 6.

We can apply two ternary functions `f` and `g` in sequence, and if `f(g(k)) == g(f(k))` holds for all `k` in `S`, then the functions *commute*.
Your task is to verify whether this is the case.

### Input

Your inputs are two integers in the inclusive range from 0 to 26.
They represent two ternary functions `f` and `g`.
Input must be taken in decimal, binary or unary (string of `1`s) format.

### Output

Your output is a [truthy value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) if `f` and `g` commute, and a falsey value if they don't.
You may not assume that the inputs are ordered.

### Examples

Consider the inputs 5 and 16.
They encode the ternary functions

```
f(0) = 2; f(1) = 1; f(2) = 0
g(0) = 1; g(1) = 2; g(2) = 1
```

We have `f(g(1)) == f(2) == 0` and `g(f(1)) == g(1) == 2`, so `f` and `g` don't commute and the correct output is falsey.

On the other hand, the inputs 3 and 10 encode the ternary functions

```
f(0) = 0; f(1) = 1; f(2) = 0
g(0) = 1; g(1) = 0; g(2) = 1
```

and it can be verified that `f(g(k)) == g(f(k))` holds for all `k` in `S`.
Then the correct output is truthy.

Here is the 27×27 table of all possible inputs, with `+` marking a truthy output and `-` a falsey output:

```
+ - - + - - + - - + - - + - - + - - + - - + - - + - -
- + - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - + - -
+ - - + - - - - - - + - - + - - - - + - - + - - - - -
- - - - + - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - - - + - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - + - - - - -
+ - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - - - - - + - - - + - - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - + - - + - - - - -
+ - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - + - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - - - - - + - - - + - - - - - - - - - + - - - - -
+ + - - - - - - - - - - + + - - - - - - - + + - - - -
- - - + + + - - - - - - + + + - - - - - - + + + - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - + + - - - - - - + - - - - -
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - + - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - + - + - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - + + - - - -
+ - - + - - - - + - - - - - - - - - + - - + - - - - +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - + - - - - +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + + - - - - +
+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
- - - - - - - - - - - - + + - - - + - - - + + - - - +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - + - - - - + - + + - +
+ - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - + + - +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - + +
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - + + + + + + + + +
```

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

Comment: Can the input be an array with the two numbers?

Comment: @DonMuesli That's allowed as per [consensus on Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/defaults-for-reading-several-pieces-of-input).

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
+13ḃ3Um0ị2/⁼/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KzEz4biDM1VtMOG7izIv4oG8Lw&input=&args=MywgMTA) or [verify all 27×27 cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KzEz4biDM1VtMOG7izIv4oG8LwoyN1LigJnhuZcyw4figqxzMjfhu4vigJwrLeKAnWrigqzigbZq4oG3&input=).

#### How it works

```
+13ḃ3Um0ị2/⁼/  Main link. Argument: [f, g] (encoded as integers)

+13            Add 13 ([1, 1, 1] in base 3) to f and g.
   ḃ3          Convert f + 13 and g + 13 to bijective base 3.
               Bijective base 3 uses the digits 1 to 3 instead of 0 to 2.
               This yields [[f(2)+1, f(1)+1, f(0)+1], [g(2)+1, g(1)+1, g(0)+1]].
               The increments account for 1-based indexing.
     U         Reverse each digit array.
               This yields [[f(0)+1, f(1)+1, f(2)+1], [g(0)+1, g(1)+1, g(2)+1]].
      m0       Concatenate the list with a reversed copy of itself.
        ị2/    Split the result into pairs, and reduce each one by indexing.
               This computes g○f and f○g.
          ⁼/   Reduce by match; return 1 iff g○f = f○g.
```

Comment: I've copied your idea of verifying all test cases and displaying the matrix :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
I:PII$YAZ{Y:)1Mw)=
```

Truthy is an array with all ones. Falsy is an array containing at least one zero.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=STpQSUkkWUFae1k6KTFNdyk9&input=WzUgMTZd) or [verify all cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mjc6cUhaXiEiQCAgICAgICAgICAgICAlIHByZXBhcmUgaW5wdXRzCkk6UElJJFlBWntZOikxTXcpPSAgICAgJSBhY3R1YWwgY29kZQpBMnZdMjdFZVEnLSsgJ3cpISAgICAgICUgcmVhcnJhbmdlIG91dHB1dHMgZm9yIGRpc3BsYXkK&input=) (takes a few seconds).

```
       % implicitly input an array of two numbers
I:P    % push [3 2 1]
I      % push 3
I$     % specify that the next function takes 3 inputs
YA     % convert input to base 3 with alphabet [3 2 1] and 3 digits. Gives 2x3 array
Z{     % convert into cell of two cells, one with each row
Y:     % split cell array. We have two arrays on the stack, one per function
)      % index operation to compute f ∘ g. Function composition is indexing
1M     % push the two arrays again
w      % swap the two arrays
)      % index operation to compute g ∘ f
=      % test for equality element-wise
       % implicitly display
```

Comment: I think usually only the empty list is considered falsy.

Comment: @Timtech [That depends on the language.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194) In MATL, arrays that contains zeroes are falsy.

Comment: Okay, just checking...

Comment: @Timtech Sure! [Here it is](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) in more detail: _An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric)_

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 61 bytes

```python
lambda m,n:all(n/3**(m/i%3)%3==m/3**(n/i%3)%3for i in[1,3,9])
```

Given an input `i`, we can implement the function represented by `n` by doing `n/3**i%3` to extract the `i`th ternary digit of `n`. The function checks that the same result is gotten for each of `0,1,2` when applying the functions in either order. Actually, since the first step is doing `3**`, this tests with `[1,3,9]` instead.

The code reuse looks wasteful, but I didn't see a better way. Compare:

```python
q=lambda x,i:x/3**i%3;lambda m,n:all(q(m,q(n,i))==q(n,q(m,i))for i in[0,1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 68 bytes

```
(a,b)=>![0,1,2].some(n=>t(a,t(b,n))-t(b,t(a,n)),t=(a,n)=>a/3**n%3|0)
```

Unfortunately base 3 conversion was too expensive:

```
(a,b)=>[0,1,2].every(n=>a[b[n]]==b[a[n]],g=a=>(27+a).toString(3).slice(1),a=g(a),b=g(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 77 bytes

```
Reverse[#][[#2+{1,1,1}]]==Reverse[#2][[#+{1,1,1}]]&@@IntegerDigits[{##},3,3]&
```

Mathematica's One-based indexing strikes again!

Comment: Shorter to assign `{1,1,1}` to a variable and use that.